# when an action sheet is visible in a mode (i.e. portrait), should it rotate in the other one (i.e. landscape)?

Tags: iphone, landscape, uiactionsheet

I have an app that supports both orientations.
When an action sheet is displayed in portrait mode, the view doesn't rotate in landscape mode. Should it be so? or normally the view should rotate and the action sheet resize?

Thank you in advance.

Fran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... The action sheet will be displayed in the orientation it is originally displayed. It will not rotate.

Try it with an official app like Mail or Notes.

Comment: Thank you :) I've tried with Mail and the action sheet doesn't rotate.